# the relationship between the parameter estimates

Tags: regression

For linear regression, what does it mean "the relationship between the parameter estimates" - what is the purpose of study it and how the relationship is found normally?

Comment: Sounds like a "covariance matrix" discussion.

Comment: Though I have upvoted your question ?   I can not understand the the things you are working/ looking at without appropriate context or goal ? Give a few more details or illustrate.